# Auto extracting software for Linux?

Tags: linux, automation, extract

Do anyone know if there's some decent software which auto extracts anything which gets downloaded (to f.e. ~/Downloads)? If, let's say, I download x.tar, it would automatically extract it to x (folder).

Comment: I'd imagine some combination of cron and batch scripts would do it, but I don't know much about cron.

Comment: You could make an applciation to do some polling to check for new tarballs. This is interesting...

Comment: The question is unclear, let me rephrase it and see if that's what you want: whenever something new appears in the directory ~/Downloads, this stuff should look at it, identify if it's a tarball or other archive format, and if so extract it to another folder??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe try a little mini-daemon along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash

DOWNLOAD_DIR=~/Downloads

while true;
do
    for file in $DOWNLOAD_DIR/*.tar*;
    do
        if [ -f $file ]
        then
            tar xf $file
            if [ $? -eq 0 ] # remove if successfully extracted
            then rm $file
            fi
        fi
    done
    sleep 5
done
```

Just start that running and away you go.  I'm not sure what the performance implications of a bash forever loop would be, but just looking at it in `top` it doesn't seem to be too bad (i.e. it isn't in there.)  You could boost the sleep time if necessary.

Comment: +1 Better way would be to use the inotify command line interfaces
http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/#info
You could  change the script to just run when the folder contents is modified. I think this would be the best way to go about this problem

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about inotify-tools.  You're right, that would be much better than constantly polling in the script.

Comment: New link https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/wiki

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fsniper](https://github.com/l3ib/fsniper), which makes use of inotify.

From the fsniper homepage:

> Common uses include making a single drop directory for all things from a webbrowser etc,  and having semi-intelligent scripts figure out what to do with those files. You write the scripts yourself.

Answer (score -1):

It's not automatic, but "right click > extract here" for gnome extracts it into a folder of the same name.

Comment: I know that, but I would love this procedure automated.

Comment: And that's what hackers are about. Probably superusers too...